Template specialization for enums
I have a generic template class, that I do not want (unable) to change
template <typename TData>
class Printer {
 public:
    bool Write(std::ostream& ostr, const TData& data) const {
        ostr << data;
        return true;
    }
};

I want to implement a specialized class for Printer that works for enums only
template <typename TThatIsEnum>
class Printer{
 public:
    bool Write(std::ostream& ostr, const TThatIsEnum& data) const {
        static Printer<int> int_printer;

        return int_printer.Write(ostr, static_cast<int>(data));
    }
};

Is this possible without adding that additional template parameter to generic template?

As it stands, in C++17, you don't have anything to specialize the primary template on. Not in a way that can detect arbitrary type traits.
The standard procedure is to add another dummy parameter to the primary.
template <typename TData, typename = void>
class Printer {
public:
    bool Write(std::ostream& ostr, const TData& data) const {
        ostr << data;
        return true;
    }
};

It's "internal" and not meant to be specified by client code. Instead, clients only specify the first, and the template mechanism figures out the second. A specialization would look like this
template <typename Enum>
class Printer<Enum, std::enable_if_t<std::is_enum_v<Enum>>> {
    Printer<std::underlying_type_t<Enum>> _delegate;
public:
    bool Write(std::ostream& ostr, const Enum& data) const {
        return _delegate.Write(ostr, static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<Enum>>(data));
    }
};

When choosing a specialization from the client's argument, the compiler will instantiate the traits. For non-enums std::enable_if_t<...> is ill-formed, so we fall back to the primary. It has a default argument for the second parameter, so it will work.
For enums std::enable_if_t<...> will be void, and so we have a valid specialization (that matches possible arguments for the primary). We can supply arbitrary arguments for the primary (Printer<char, int> for instance), but not every pair of arguments will be valid for our specialization (int will never match void). On the other hand, all valid arguments for our specialization will fit the primary as well (this is why the default argument is void, so it matches), so the specialization is indeed considered more specialized.
I also took the liberty of improving your implementation to ask the enum what its underlying type is (and not assume int). And instead of a static, using a member delegate is more friendly for a library. The object sizes are the same but with fewer surprises.
On a closing note, you should know C++20 simplifies this by a lot with type constraints and concepts. In C++20 we can write
template <typename TData>
class Printer {
  // As you did
};

template <typename Enum>
  requires std::is_enum_v<Enum>
class Printer {
  // As I did
};

No dummy parameters needed, since constraints become first class citizens.
